# .replaceWith jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery's .replaceWith() function for a webapp I am designing. My HTML is this:

```
{% for service in services %}                   
<div id="service" name="name" value="{{service.name}}">
{{service.name}} <a href='main/name/{{service.name}}'> Click if you want to see more </a>
<div id="rating_services">
<form name="rating">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="star1" id="star_1" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
<input name="star1" id="star_2" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
<input name="star1" id="star_3" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
<input name="star1" id="star_4" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
<input name="star1" id="star_5" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/> 
<input type="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Rate this agency!">
</form>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

And my javascript is this:

```
$(function() 
{  
$(".button").click(function()
  {  
  $('#rating_services').replaceWith("<div id='thanks'> Thanks! </div>");    
  }
});
```

What I want to do is if the user rates. A thanks is displayed instead of the ratings. However, the information is displayed within a for loop (for displaying multiple "agencies"). So, I can only rate one by one, and one at a time at that. How can I change it so that I can rate out of order? I tried to change the div `id` to `{{forloop.counter}}`, but then javascript can handle the `#` and the `{{forloop.counter}}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of loop you are talking about. Please edit your question to show an example of how the loop works - if that means multiple `<div>` or whatever.

Comment: It is hard to understand what the issue you are having is, I don't see a for loop, the code you posted appears valid. Can you elaborate on your actual problem posting relevant code as necessary?

Comment: Seems to be missing a `);` in your click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have multiple `div`s with the ID of "rating_services" as a result of your loop?

If so, instead of hard-coding the ID of the `div` you'd like to replace, you should give each of the `div`s a class (i.e. `class="rating_services"` instead of `id="rating_services"`), then retrieve the `div` dynamically using the jQuery `closest()` function, as below:

```
$(function()
{
  $(".button").click(function()
    {
      $(this).closest('.rating_services').replaceWith("<div id='thanks'> Thanks! </div>");
    }
  );
});
```

More on the closest() function here:
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name=rating]").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#rating_services').replaceWith("<div id='thanks'> Thanks! </div>");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FrSCA/1/)

Instead of binding a `click` handler to the submit button, bind a `submit` handler to the forms and [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) the event so the page doesn't submit to itself.

---

Also, if your template generates duplicate IDs, that's invalid HTML and the JS won't work properly.

You should use classes instead:

```
<div class="rating_services">
```

And JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name=rating]").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.rating_services').replaceWith("<div id='thanks'> Thanks! </div>");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FrSCA/2/)

Comment: @sam Sending an [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request before overwriting the form. Or if your intention is to submit it, comment out the `preventDefault` line.

Comment: Ok thank you. So right before the replaceWith put in an Ajax request?

Comment: Yes, either ajax or one of its shorthands such as [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) so you could do something like `$.post('urlToPost', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ /*callback function*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

Since the click is on the button, perhaps put the id on the button

```
$('input.button#'+forloop.counter).click(function() 
 {
$('#rating_services'+ forloop.counter).replaceWith(...
 }
```

that might be a lot of event handlers though so you might want to use

```
$('div.parent_div').delegate('input.button#'+forloop.counter, ...)..
```